# Google analytics push data set to report

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have created data set with user data type in google analytics. Through api i push internal data to data set. How can i bring data from data set to google analytics report?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: In google analytics on admin page i went to data import and there i created data set. Using api i push my custom data to created data set. After that i created custom report in which i pointed custom params as in data set, but data from data set doesn't appear in my custom report.